# error C2761 member function redeclaration not allowed

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I've encountered a problem(error C2761) while writing specializations for a class. My classes are as follows:

```
class Print{
public:
    typedef class fontA;
    typedef class fontB;
    typedef class fontC;
    typedef class fontD;

    template<class T>
    void startPrint(void) { return; };
    virtual bool isValidDoc(void) = 0;
};
```

I have a class `QuickPrint` which inherits the `Print` class:

```
class QuickPrint : public Print {
       ...
};
```

The error occurs when I try to write specializations for the `startPrint` method:

```
template<>        // <= C2716 error given here
void QuickPrint::startPrint<fontA>(void)
{
      /// implementation
}

template<>        // <= C2716 error given here
void QuickPrint::startPrint<fontB>(void)
{
     /// implementation
}
```

The error appears for the remaining specializations as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickPrint does not have a template member function named startPrint, so specializing QuickPrint::startPrint is an error. If you repeat the template definition in QuickPrint the specializations are okay:

```
class QuickPrint : public Print {
   template<class T>
    void startPrint(void) { return; };
 };

template<>        // <= C2716 error given here
void QuickPrint::startPrint<Print::fontA>(void)
{
      /// implementation
}
```

But if the goal here is to be able to call into QuickPrint polymorphically, you're in trouble, because the template function in Print can't be marked virtual.

Comment: Thanks, adding the default implementation into the derived class worked.

Comment: That appears to be dangerous. If now some function of `Print` calls `startPrint`, the specialization he wrote is not chosen because he didn't specialize Print's member function template.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said; it's not polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class QuickPrint : public Print {
    template<class T>
    void startPrint(void) { Print::startPrint<T>(); };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is this line:

```
template<class T> 
void startPrint(void) { return; };
```

You already provide a function body, but then try to redefine it again (using specialization), which won't work.

Remove that function body and it should work.

To define a default behaviour, provide a default value for template paramter `T` and then add a single specialization for that one.